# Publishing a paper in cryptography

Tags: rsa

I have written a mathematical paper in cryptography and I want to publish it but I don't know any professors in the field to collaborate with them. So what should I do and how to get contacts that could help me setting up with this work?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. This is better to be asked on Meta, chat, or academics. SInce you tagged RSA, did you break it?

Comment: @kelalaka Yes! I broke it but not in polynomial time or space!

Comment: To publish this, I'd think that you'd need to show some improvement over existing attacks on RSA, unless it's an interesting new technique, which may then be more suitable for mathematical journals/conferences. I suggest you follow @kelalaka's suggestion about where to ask.

Comment: in crypto you could just post it on eprint.iacr.org and go from there